# Force grid of images to be centered alone on a page

Tags: positioning

I'm always facing the same problem when it comes to images. I sometimes need to place an image centered alone on a page but it keeps sticking to the top of the page. I used for some images the `minipage` environment. But now I need to do this with a grid of 20 images and nothing is working.

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{25.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{26.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{27.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{28.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Al}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{29.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{30.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{31.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{32.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{33.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Re}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{34.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{35.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{36.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{37.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{38.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Ta}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{39.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{40.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{41.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{42.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{43.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{W}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{44.png}}\\
\end{figure}
```

Is there a "clean" way to do this for all type of images, because this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{25.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{26.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{27.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{28.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{Al}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{29.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{30.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{31.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{32.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{33.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{Re}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{34.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{35.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{36.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{37.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{38.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{Ta}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{39.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{40.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{41.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{42.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{43.png}}&
\subcaptionbox*{W}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{44.png}}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

I use `\vspace*{\fill}` to center the figure vertically.  I like using tabular for something with this many figures but you don't need to if you don't want to.  I used the package `geometry` with standard 1in margin and everything fit.  Is your 5th picture having a width `0.15in` a typo?  As it is, I assumed that is what you wanted.

[image]

In case the 5th image size was a typo:

I had to set the margin to `.75in`.  If you want to use the 1in margin for your document, you can set the margin of that page alone `.75in` to get it centered too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm now using the `float` function correctly. For many tables and images in my document I used this `\hspace*{\fill}

\vspace{\fill}

\pagebreak

\newpage
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
\clearpage`

I don't even know what this is, I just copied pasted it from somewhere. But now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem may occur if your figure exceeds the right margin.  You didn't include a full MWE, so it couldn't be checked.  However, here is one way to achieve what I think is your goal, if the right margin is not at issue.

In the first figure, I use `\includegraphics`, just to show it works.  For the rest, I left it as a `\rule`, for simplicity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldsyntax]{stackengine}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait]{geometry}
% DEFINE TEXT LIMITS ON LETTER PAPER ACCORDING TO ARL STYLE.
  \setlength\paperheight {11in}
  \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}
  \setlength\textwidth {7in}
  \setlength\oddsidemargin {-0.3in}
  \setlength\evensidemargin {-0.3in}
  \setlength\topmargin {-0.5in}
  \setlength\textheight {9.0in}
  \raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\myfiga{\stackunder[3pt]{%
  \includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{demo}}{0,1 s}}
\def\myfigb{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{25 s}}
\def\myfigc{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{750 s}}
\def\myfigd{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{1618,55 s}}
\def\myfige{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{Al}}
\def\myfigf{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{0,1 s}}
\def\myfigg{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{25 s}}
\def\myfigh{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{750 s}}
\def\myfigi{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{1618,55 s}}
\def\myfigj{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{Re}}
\def\myfigk{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{0,1 s}}
\def\myfigl{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{25 s}}
\def\myfigm{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{750 s}}
\def\myfign{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{1618,55 s}}
\def\myfigo{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{Ta}}
\def\myfigp{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{0,1 s}}
\def\myfigq{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{25 s}}
\def\myfigr{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{750 s}}
\def\myfigs{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{1618,55 s}}
\def\myfigt{\stackunder[3pt]{\rule{1.2in}{1.2in}}{W}}
\Sstackgap=1em

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Lstackgap=1.45in
\Longstack{%
{\protect\myfiga} {\protect\myfigf} {\protect\myfigk} {\protect\myfigp}%
}%
\hspace{1em}%
\Longstack{%
{\protect\myfigb} {\protect\myfigg} {\protect\myfigl} {\protect\myfigq}%
}%
\hspace{1em}%
\Longstack{%
{\protect\myfigc} {\protect\myfigh} {\protect\myfigm} {\protect\myfigr}%
}%
\hspace{1em}%
\Longstack{%
{\protect\myfigd} {\protect\myfigi} {\protect\myfign} {\protect\myfigs}%
}
\hspace{1em}%
\Longstack{%
{\protect\myfige} {\protect\myfigj} {\protect\myfigo} {\protect\myfigt}%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[EDIT: This MWE uses obsolete stackengine syntax for setting stackgap lengths (e.g., \Sstackgap=1ex), which prevented scalable lengths from scaling under a fontsize change. Version 2 of the package (submitted JUL-11-13) remedies the problem with a small syntax change.]